# How to evaluate B-Splines in Keras custom loss

Tags: tensorflow, for-loop, keras, spline

I am working on parameterizing b-splines knots and control points with deep learning. To do this, I have a model which outputs the knots and control points, and I want to let the model learn by implementing a custom loss function which evaluates the b-spline and then calculates the mean squared error against the actual curve. Hopefully, the model will learn to output the correct knots and control points.

However, Keras custom loss function requires all statements to be wrapped in backend functions. From [scipy B-spline docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html), this is how the function will look like normally.

```
def B(x, k, i, t):
   if k == 0:
      return 1.0 if t[i] <= x < t[i+1] else 0.0
   if t[i+k] == t[i]:
      c1 = 0.0
   else:
      c1 = (x - t[i])/(t[i+k] - t[i]) * B(x, k-1, i, t)
   if t[i+k+1] == t[i+1]:
      c2 = 0.0
   else:
      c2 = (t[i+k+1] - x)/(t[i+k+1] - t[i+1]) * B(x, k-1, i+1, t)
   return c1 + c2

def bspline(x, t, c, k):
   n = len(t) - k - 1
   assert (n >= k+1) and (len(c) >= n)
   return sum(c[i] * B(x, k, i, t) for i in range(n))
```

I know that for simple statements such as summation, I can use K.sum, and for if-else statements, I can use K.switch. However, I do not know how to implement for-loops in Keras. Is there a straight forward way to compute B-spline curves in Keras? (converting the above code into Keras backend)